# How do you call a function that is the gradient of a function?

Tags: convex-analysis, multivalued-functions, gradient-flows

Let us consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exists a real-valued function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\nabla F(x) =f(x)$. 
How would you call such a function?

Furthermore if $F$ is convex, is there a name for this type of function $f$?

Comment: For domain $\mathbb R^n$--or more generally a simply connected domain--the condition should be vanishing of some set of differential operators applied to $f$.  In $\mathbb R^3$, it is the vanishing of the curl of $f$.  A vector field with vanishing curl is said to be **irrotational**.  I don't know if that term is also used for the corresponding condition on $\mathbb R^n$ .  Perhaps you will need to look up the "de Rham chain complex".

Comment: A potential. ${}{}$